# My character keeps jumping around in NetHack. Why?

Tags: nethack

I've spent quite a while on my NetHack game (for me), and I've managed to get up a few levels. However, my character has (annoyingly) started to randomly jump around to different parts of the level - which is both a blessing and a curse.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Sounds like a [case of teleportitis](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Teleportitis). You can get this effect in a number of ways. If you're not wearing a ring of teleportation, then it's probably because you ate the corpse of a teleporting creature like a leprechaun.

Comment: I thought this was a joke answer at first. Then I googled nethack and followed the link. What the?

Comment: Nethack can be fun like that.

Comment: Reading that page, I think it was a tengu. :) I'm impressed, though. This was a 'test' question to see if there was anyone who could actually answer NetHack questions on here. Finally, somewhere non-spam-infested! (*ahem* RGRN via Google Groups).

Comment: @Lucas, just wait for this place to become public :D @Hobodave that'd make an excellent question.

Comment: @hobodave - Playing Nethack is one continuous, ongoing joke. A sick, twisted one. ;) @Lucas Jones - Thanks. I'm glad to know all those months lost to this game weren't *entirely* useless. ;)

Comment: @ire_and_curses: I'm still set to lose many more months, unfortunately. Maybe I'm just not cut out for demigodhood.

Comment: @hobodave, Jurily: My "favourite" was always the bag of holding inside itself vanishes, basically, just to annoy you.

Answer (score -2):

As [ire_and_curses says](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/430/my-character-keeps-jumping-around-in-nethack-why/463#463), it is teleportitis, but it does wear off after a while. The greatest blessings are bank robbery and shop-lifting!

Comment: I don't think that teleportitis ever wears off.

Comment: Yes, teleportitis will stay with you like an annoying case of hiccups until you either have it stolen by a gremlin or gain teleport control.