# Do pets gain experience when being ridden?

Tags: nethack

If I'm riding my Pony will he gain experience and eventually become a Horse (and then a Warhorse)?

Comment: This is an hilarious question if one does not know what you are talking about and take it out of context (i did)

Comment: @Ben: gaming.SE has the funniest question titles ever. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5089 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13441

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat. ah, yes, good ones :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ridden pets level up as normal - by killing monsters. Note, however, that ridden pets are more docile. They will not attack a monster unless attacked first. Since monsters will randomly attack you or the pet when you are mounted, this may mean your pet gets fewer kills (and thus experience) than it otherwise would.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much!