# What is the meaning of the three kinds of penetration?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In a Tank Characteristics, it says "Average Penetration 45/49/22 (in mm)". The same applies to damage, where it uses this split into three formats.

This is how much armor (in mm) it could penetrate, but why are there three numbers?

Comment: @DavidYell [I](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) [doubt](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/my-wife-is-stuck-in-a-wall-can-i-save-her) [that](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-can-i-keep-monsters-out-of-my-nether-regions) [highly.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/how-to-pray-safely-to-god)

Comment: I just fell off my chair.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the chaps I found talking about it over [here](http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/29905-gun-penetration-stats/) it's to do with the different ammunition types:

> ```
> AP / HEAT / HE
> ```
>
> penetration is related to the shell type.
>   AP is the "standard" round
>   HEAT has the most penetration, buts its bought with gold = you pay with real money
>   HE has low penetration and high damage, but it will always do some damage when you don't penetrate the armor, its used against high tiers when your gun can't penetrate them.

Comment: AP / APCR / HE applies for tanks and some tank destroyers whilist HE / HEAT / AP applies mainly for artillery pieces. Take into account that HE and HEAT shells penetrate the specified armor not caring the distance between you and target, while for AP and APCR the penetration is inversely proportional to the distance between you and target.

Comment: There's also Premium HE which is used by a few SPG guns.   Premium HE is usually similar to standard HE but has a larger splash radius.

Comment: That's correct! Take a look at this guide: http://www.altergamer.com/world-of-tanks-guide-the-long-way-to-the-tiger/ for more details on gameplay.