# How should I feed a cat?

Tags: stendhal

In [Stendhal](http://stendhalgame.org/), you can own a cat. How should I feed it? It always tells me it's starving. I  does not catch rats or mice.

Comment: Once you figure out **how**, refer to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/ for ideas on what and when. Mostly kidding, but these question titles are great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself. In Ados City, NPC [Felina](http://stendhalgame.org/world/atlas.html?poi=Felina&zoom=3) sells cat. She tells you how to feed it as well.

> Cats love chicken and fish.
>   Just place a piece on the ground and
>   your cat will run over to eat it. You
>   can right-click on her and choose
>   'Look' at any time, to check up on her
>   weight; she will gain one unit of
>   weight for every piece of chicken she
>   eats.