# Does eating werefoo corpses give lycantropy?

Tags: nethack

A wererat just died at my sword, failing to transmit its disease to me. However, it also left a corpse for me to eat. I'm hungry. My pet drags it to me, bad sign, but then again it does so for lichen corpses too and they're perfectly safe to eat.

Is it safe to eat?

Comment: [Anon's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/does-eating-werefoo-corpses-give-lycantropy/15050#15050) answers your titular question. But just to note - were{foo} count as humans. So in terms of "is it safe to eat", keep in mind [how that figures in](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat).

Comment: @Grace I did look at that question first but didn't find (literally: `ctrl-f were`) anything about it :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't cover lycanthrope. I'm just commenting about eating humans.

Comment: +1 for making me google search "werefoo". In an awesome display of recursion, this question was the #1 result.

Comment: FYI: Your pet doesn't eat lichen corpses because your pet's a carnivore and lichens are vegetarian food. If your pet was a vegetarian (e.g. a horse), it'd eat the lichen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not safe to eat. It will give you lycanthropy. Also, if you are human, it is considered cannibalism.

[Nethack Wiki Corpse page](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Corpses)

[Nethack Wiki Werecreature page](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Werecreature)

Answer (score 5):

Eating a were{foo}'s corpse will always confer lycanthropy.