# After I beat the Kayran, what can I do with its corpse?

Tags: the-witcher-2

After a long struggle, I managed to beat the Kayran. Great! Now I have a neat Kayran Trophy, a Kayran Hide, and other Kayran bits to round out my loot.

I know the Kayren Hide can be crafted into either Kayran Hide Armor, or a Kayren Hide Armor Enhancement, and the Kayren Trophy is already useable as-is.

But what use are the rest of the Kayren bits, specifically the "Kayran Tissue" and the "Kayran Eyes"? Are they just useful as relatively rare alchemical ingredients (contains Vitriol!), or are there more recipes involving them that I'm not yet aware of?

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed the game and I did not find any other uses for the Kayran bits that you mention. Either sell them or use them as alchemical ingredients.

Comment: The armor is not that great either. You will get some much better plans soon.

Answer (score 2):

Someone in the village (Cedric?) had the blueprint for some sort of armor from Kayren's leftovers.

Comment: Indeed! I mention that in my question. I was specifically referring to the Kayran Tissue I picked up.

Comment: why this got voted down so hard is beyond me..

Answer (score 0):

Kayran eyes are needed from the lady who asks about Newboys medallion (she is some kind of herbalist, further north of where Cedric stands).

She says she can re-envoke the power of the medalian with a trolls tounge, Kayran eyes, Kiss of Death (or was it Nectar of Death?) and a fourth item I can not remember.