# When should I eat people?

Tags: adom

The in-game manual for ADOM is massive, and I don't see anything on the main screen that resembles a hunger stat. How do I know when I should start eating all these corpses and foodstuffs I'm piling up?

Comment: There must be a joke in there somewhere...

Comment: [What is it with our community and eating people?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above answer is wrong, and there is a significant downside to being Satiated and Bloated, namely -5 speed for each of them (i.e. -10 speed when bloated). It also decreases your DV somewhat.

Also, if you reach Starving!, you will die in 100-150 turns depending on the toughness stat.

Comment: I havn't played ADOM in ages but as I recall being Bloated also abuses a couple stats...

Answer (score 0):

There are five different hunger indicators:
  - Bloated (Can't eat any more)
  - Satiated
  - Normal (No indicator)
  - Hungry (Usually first indication that you should eat something)
  - Starving! (The longer you stay here, the more stats you lose.  I don't think it's permanent, but not 100%)

So if you're managing to pile up lots of food, eat!  The only downside to Bloated is if you find a corpse that grants an ability you want (ie. troll, blink dog, etc.).  You'll have to wait to digest before you can eat it and gain the ability.