# Should I eat corpses or destroy them?

Tags: neo-scavenger

I find it useless to simply kill a bandit (or similar) and just destroy the corpse, I've read about the player going crazy if eating human meat for too long. I don't know if I should eat the people or avoid them.

I'm also wondering about eating at Zom Zom's "Free" meal they have...

Comment: [Why is it always back to eating corpses?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

Comment: Generally I don't destroy corpses either... I just walk away and leave them to rot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The penalty for eating human meat isn't too severe, but the penalty for mistakenly trying to sell human meat at the Junk Market is very severe (though you do get one warning).  For that reason, I would suggest leaving any human corpses alone.

With the right traits, non-cannibalistic food is pretty easy to come by.  If you're at serious risk of dying, though, eating a human is better than starvation.

The "going crazy" penalty for eating human meat for too long is a greatly increased hunger rate.  There is flavor text describing much worse effects, but currently there is no other in-game effect.

Comment: So is the increased hunger equal to the negative metabolism trait?

Comment: @Codingale Much worse.  The wiki says "from full to starvation in two days".

Comment: So I'd have to kill someone every day or so just to make it by? That makes eating it often very bad...

Comment: @Codingale Unpleasant, but certainly survivable.  Also, possibly curable - someone on the forums reporting having his early-stage cannibalism cured at the ATN Enclave.

Comment: Hum, happen to have a link for that?

Comment: Here's the (single-post) thread: [Interesting Event at the ATN Enclave -SPOILERS-](http://bluebottlegames.com/main/node/3151)